Understanding epsilon-delta proof regarding dense sets
I'm currently self-studying using Spivak's "Calculus" and I wanted to check on my understanding regarding an epsilon-delta proof for dense sets. The first problem was the following:

If $f$ is a continuous function and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in a dense set $A$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$

Here'e my proof for this:
Let $x_0$ be an arbitrary point. Then, $f$ will be continuous on it. Thus, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. Since $A$ is dense, there exists an $x^*\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ such that $x^*\in A$. Thus, $f(x^*) = 0$. So, $|f(x^*) - f(x_0)| = |-f(x_0)| = |f(x_0)|$. If we assume that $f(x_0)\neq 0$, then $|f(x_0)| > 0$. Thus, let $\epsilon = \frac{f(x_0)}{2}$. Now, we have a contradiction since $|f(x_0)| > \epsilon$. Thus, $f(x_0) = 0$.
But after this, I was having trouble with the following problem (it's paraphrased for convenience):

Prove that if $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x\in A$ where $A$ is dense then $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x$. Why does this not work if we replace $\geq$ with $>$?

For this, I just created a new function: $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)\geq 0$. Now, the problem is about showing that $h(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$. I did a similar thing as the previous proof, finding an $x^*$ within $\delta$. Thus, $h(x^*)\geq 0$. Now, consider $|h(x^*) - h(x_0)|$. Suppose $h(x_0) < 0$. Then, let $k = -h(x_0)$ and $k > 0$. $|h(x^*) + k| > 0$. So, let $\epsilon = \frac{|h(x^*) + k|}{2}$ and you're done.
But, I was wondering why a similar approach can't be taken for $f(x) > g(x)$. Here's my line of reasoning for the same:
My first proof worked because $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ ultimately required $|f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. And, regardless of the choice of $\delta$, $f(x_0)$ is always fixed. Thus, $\forall \delta>0$, $|f(x_0)|\not<\epsilon$ and, therefore, $\forall\delta>0, |f(x) - f(x_0)| \not< \epsilon$. Hence, $\not\exists\delta>0$ such that $|f(x) - f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ if it is assumed that $f(x_0)\neq0$.
For the second proof, $h(x_0)$ is fixed. Hence, if $h(x_0) < 0$, then $k = -h(x_0)$ means that $k$ is also fixed. Thus, $\forall\delta>0, k > 0\implies h(x^*) + k > 0$ since $h(x^*)$, although variable depending on $\delta$, is always greater than or equal to zero. Hence, $\forall \delta > 0, |h(x^*) + k|\not<\epsilon$. Thus, $\not\exists\delta>0$ such that $|h(x^*) + k| < \epsilon$.
Now, here's why we cannot replace $\geq$ with $>$. Suppose we could. Then, $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) > 0$. Now, we need to show that $h(x_0) > 0$. So, for contradiction, suppose that $h(x_0) = 0$. Then, $|h(x^*) - h(x_0)| = |h(x^*)|$. Now, $h(x^*)$, although greater than zero, is not fixed. It depends on the choice of $\delta$. Hence, unlike the previous two proofs, we cannot derive contradictions.
Is this line of reasoning correct? Or is there another reason for why the proof does not work?

The line of reasoning is fine but to really complete the argument you should give an explicit example.

As said in comments it is good to give an example. As you have guessed, $h(x^{\star})$ may go to $0$ as $x^\star$ goes to $x_0$. You can easily construct the examples.
Consider
$g(x) = 2x^2$ and $h(x) =x^2$ on $[0, 1]$. Clearly, $(0,1]$ is a desnse subset of $[0,1]$. On $(0,1]$ both $h$ and $g$ are continuous and $g(x)>h(x)$. However $g(0)=h(0)$.
